# How can I configure SQL Server Aliases on a SQL Server Client Machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, configuration-manager

Even after installing SSMS on a SQL Server Client machine, I found that SQL Server Configuration Manager would not run.  Manually loading the mof file via [Microsoft's Instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/956013/error-message-when-you-open-sql-server-configuration-manager-in-sql-se) was sufficient to repair the "Cannot connect to WMI provider" error, but this only caused the 32 bit configuration manager to show up.  I also want to configure 64-bit aliases.

Historically, I've avoided this problem by using the SQL Server Install Media to install SSMS, but I was hoping this was no longer necessary now that SSMS was released separately.  Absent a documented recommendation from Microsoft, I'd rather avoid the commonly suggested hack of copying `sqlmgmprovider.dll` from other machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `cliconfg.exe` instead.  This is shipped with Windows.

`c:\windows\system32\cliconfg.exe` - 64Bit aliases
`c:\windows\syswow64\cliconfg.exe` - 32Bit aliases